# I have completed my site in dreamweaver, Do i just upload my root folder to my host now?

Tags: hosting

So as the title says, I have completed my site for my first client in Dreamweaver ( still studying in college ), Do i just upload it to their hosting site of choice and will all the links work? I know how to upload just curious about how the links like images and my root folder will stay in tact.

Answer (score 0):

Upload all your files to your live server's 'htdocs' or 'public-html' folder. All your links should work fine, if done properly. As far as you move all your folders (images, css, etc) to the live server everything will work.

Dreamweaver doesn't require any special thing or configuration before deploying, you can even deploy directly from Dreamweaver to be super sure nothing breaks while deploying to the production server.

Comment: Thanks, So i just simply upload my root folder to their upload area. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's basically all you need to do,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Generally, they will. You can try it for yourself and see. As long as your refering to the images relative to your file.

Comment: Yeh perfect, All the images inside my root folder. So ill just upload my root folder and everything inside will work perfectly? :)

Comment: @C.Bw As long as your path to your images is relative to the file, yes, And not a path from a drive such as `C:/...image.jpg`